# Triply integral involving spherical coordinates - how can I proceed?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

$$
\iiint_V \frac{1}{x^2+y^2 + z^2 } dx dy dz =?
$$
where
$$
V=\{ (x,y,z)| x^2 + y^2 + (z-1)^2 \leq  1 \}.
$$

After moving to spherical coordinates I obtain:
$$
\iiint \sin \theta dr d\theta d\phi
$$
where:
$$
r-2 \cos \theta \leq 0 
$$
and I have no idea how to handle this constraint... should I take $r$ to be in a bounded region, or maybe it is better to bound $\theta$? is it possible that this one constraint actually implies two constraints (one that $r\leq -2 \cos \theta$ and the other one is that $\cos \theta \leq 0 $) ?

Will you please help me ?

THanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Limits are

$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{0}^{2cos\phi} sin\phi d\rho d\phi d\theta$

Comment: You can also use cylindrical coordinates by projecting onto YZ plane.